# How can I provide a hand-authored declaration file in a ts project?

Tags: typescript, .d.ts, declaration-files

I have these files:

- foo.ts
- foo.d.ts (hand-authored)
- bar.ts

I want to use TypeScript to generate the following output

- foo.js
- foo.d.ts (same as my hand-authored one)
- bar.ts
- bar.d.ts

TypeScript ignores my hand-authored foo.d.ts in this case and just generates a .d.ts from foo.ts. How can I get TS to pass through hand-authored .d.ts files when there is a corresponding .ts?

Comment: Why would you have definition file for ts file?

Comment: Good question. Someone asked for this feature, and I should probably go back and ask why they want it. But I'm still curious if it's possible.

Comment: I have no idea if it's possible, it doesn't really make sense. You use definition files to define JavaScript file types. If you have a TypeScript file, just define types there. What would happen with compiler if `.ts` and `.d.ts` files have conflicting type definitions? `export function Foo(): string` and `export function Foo(): number`. Which one is right? I guess compiler just ignores `.d.ts` file when there is `.ts`file there.

Comment: Yes, the compiler seems to ignore <name>.d.ts file when there is a <name>.ts

Comment: I suspect the answer is: There aren't many cases for hand-authoring a .d.ts when there is a corresponding for .ts. Unlike header files in C/C++, TS has `export`. So TS authors have the options to  keep types private, or export wider or narrower versions of a type or aggregate types from many other files and expose them together.